# Time long negative

Tags: java, android

Hey i have a problem :

log :

```
04-26 11:29:09.332 21657-21784/com.grou D/answer: -3600000
04-26 11:29:09.332 21657-21784/com.grou D/answer: 12:00:00
```

code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(TimeEnd);
Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
tsTimeEnd = timestamp.getTime();
Log.d("answer",Long.toString(timestamp.getTime()));
timestamp.setTime(tsTimeEnd);
Log.d("answer",dateFormat.format(timestamp));
```

why -3600000 ?? :(

Solution :

i'm in 24 hours i put hh or it's HH so 12:00:00 it's normal than is negatif

Comment: Exactly what you want to do b/n two dates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003498/why-does-simpledateformat-parse-gettime-return-an-incorrect-negative-value

Comment: Nop not working same problem  hour is: -1.0

Comment: your answer is correct ? ignore `-` sign?

Comment: Thx you i solved my problem lol i'm in 24 hours i put hh or it's HH so 12:00:00 it's normal than is negatif

Answer (score -1):

```
public static long getMillisFromDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(hh:mm:ss);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
    try {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    }
```

Try this out, it may help you. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Thx you i solved my problem lol i'm in 24 hours i put hh or it's HH so 12:00:00 it's normal than is negatif