# What is my mistake to convert Date into minutes?

Tags: java, duration, datetime-conversion, minute

Based on [How to convert Standard Date into minutes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221896/how-to-convert-standard-date-into-minutes-in-java) information, I follow this technique to convert date into minute, but an output is not as an expected value (e.g., 12 hour -> it should be 720 minutes).

Here is my source code

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
    Date theDate = sdf.parse ("12");
    long minutes22 = (theDate.getTime() / 1000)  / 60;
    System.out.println("Minute "+minutes22);
```

An output is -420. Can someone explain to me ?

< First problem is solved, please take a look at the comment section >

The new problem is cutting String. 
< The problem is solved as well,please take a look at comment section >

For Another Input that I have try to do my own solution,but there is problem occur after finishing cutting String. I found that duplicate value can not keep separately. I don t know why would happen because I kept in different index. Any suggestion ?

Here is another my another source code.

```
    String date = "Sun 10:00-20:00\r\n" + 
            "Fri 05:00-10:00\r\n" + 
            "Fri 16:30-23:50\r\n" + 
            "Sat 10:00-24:00\r\n" + 
            "Sun 01:00-04:00\r\n" + 
            "Sat 02:00-06:00\r\n" + 
            "Tue 03:30-18:15\r\n" + 
            "Tue 19:00-20:00\r\n" + 
            "Wed 04:25-15:14\r\n" + 
            "Wed 15:14-22:40\r\n" + 
            "Thu 00:00-23:59\r\n" + 
            "Mon 05:00-13:00\r\n" + 
            "Mon 15:00-21:00";

    List<String> Hour = new ArrayList<String>();
    int loop = 0;

    String [] replacement = {"sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"};
    String new_s = date.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ","");

    for(int j = 0;j<replacement.length;j++)
    {
        new_s = new_s.replace(replacement[j],"").replace("\r\n","");


    }

    String temp = "";
    temp = temp+new_s.replaceAll("-","");

    int show = 0;
    while(!temp.equals(""))
    {
        Hour.add(temp.substring(loop,loop+5));
        temp = temp.replace(temp.substring(0,loop+5),"");
        System.out.println("Hour "+Hour.get(show));
        show++;

    }
```

Here is the output

`Hour 10:00
Hour 20:00
Hour 05:00
Hour 16:30
Hour 23:50
Hour 24:00
Hour 01:00
Hour 04:00
Hour 02:00
Hour 06:00
Hour 03:30
Hour 18:15
Hour 19:00
Hour 04:25
Hour 15:14
Hour 22:40
Hour 00:00
Hour 23:59
Hour 13:00
Hour 15:00
Hour 21:00`

Another question -  why would it print out < 0 instead of 1200 >

```
 LocalTime froms = LocalTime.parse("20:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println("TIme "+froms.getMinute());'
```

Comment: Could it be a timezone issue?

Comment: Can also try TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(12) // 720

Comment: Try to print the date and you will see the problem, the parsing produces a wrong date. Change `hh` to `HH` will make it (up to timezone issue).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15003833/9524541)

Comment: @JasonM1 Thank you!! .  TimeUnit  solved this problem. It could be timezone issue as Sentry and Jean 's comment.

Comment: @Juan I am just confused about an output because I try to look solution serveral times in order to convert into minute ,so that might not related to calculation.

Comment: @SystemGlitch Thanks a lot .

Comment: Is there a reason you still use the old Date API ( `Date`) instead of the new one (`LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, ...)?

Comment: @Zabuza I found Date API that solved the problem with a format. I want to solve an  input String which is something like "Sun 11:00-20:00"  then cutting a String to calculate the minute  between 11.00-20.00. There's nothing to use old API but I found this one is a basic. If you have any idea please tell me.  .

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.ofHours(12).toMinutes()
```

> 720

## `java.time.Duration`

You are using troubled old legacy date-time classes. And furthermore, you are abusing by them.

The `Date` class has been replaced by the `Instant` class. Both represent a moment, a point on the timeline. Do not abuse them to represent “twelve hours”.

Apparently you want to represent a span of time unattached to the timeline. So use the class designed for that purpose, `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours(12);
```

To see the total number of minutes in the entire duration, call `toMinutes`.

```
long minutes = d.toMinutes();
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
    String input = "Sun 11:00-20:00";
    String[] fromAndTo = input.split("-");
    LocalTime from = LocalTime.parse(fromAndTo[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE H:mm", Locale.ENGLISH));
    LocalTime to = LocalTime.parse(fromAndTo[1]);
    System.out.println(Duration.between(from, to).toMinutes());
```

This printed:

> 540

### Can someone explain to me ?

You’ve got two bugs that both contribute to your incorrect result:

- You misused a `Date` for a duration and didn’t specify time zone.
- You used lowercase `hh` for hours in you format pattern string. `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12, so 12 means the same as 0 (because 12:00 AM is the same as 00:00 on a 24-hour clock).

Your `SimpleDateFormat` understood `12` as 00:00 in your local time zone (as defined by your JVM’s time zone setting). However, when you take out the milliseconds using `theDate.getTime()`, you get the milliseconds since 00:00 in UTC. Since your time zone has an offset from UTC, you get an error the magnitude of this offset.

Comment: @V.V I have try to use split("-") with another input type such as String date = "Sun 10:00-20:00\r\n" + 
    "Fri 05:00-10:00\r\n" + 
    "Fri 16:30-23:50\r\n" + 
    "Sat 10:00-24:00\r\n" + 
    "Sun 01:00-04:00\r\n" + 
    "Sat 02:00-06:00\r\n" + 
    "Tue 03:30-18:15\r\n" + 
    "Tue 19:00-20:00\r\n" + 
    "Wed 04:25-15:14\r\n" + 
    "Wed 15:14-22:40\r\n" + 
    "Thu 00:00-23:59\r\n" + 
    "Mon 05:00-13:00\r\n" + 
    "Mon 15:00-21:00";                                              < but It does not cut all of  period > Am I using split in the wrong way ??

Comment: Probably. In that case I would split on "\r\n" (or "[\r\n]+") first to split into lines, and then each line on "-".

Comment: Nice Method, but there is problem occur after finishing cutting String. I found that duplicate value can not keep separately [ In case of different day,but same period time]. I dont know why would happen because I kept in different index. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @Mr.Kim No suggestions without seeing your code. You may consider posting a new question? BTW `LocalTime.parse` won’t work for end time 24:00 either.

Comment: `temp.replace(temp.substring(0,loop+5),"")` replaces *all* occurrences of the time in question (not just the first).

Comment: Ok so i have to change to another solution. Thanks a lot  Is there any reccommend or suggestion for source code ?

Comment: An immediate suggestion would be `temp = temp.substring(5);`. But depending on your exact requirements I think that splitting on `"\r\n"` and then using the code in the answer would be better.

Comment: V.V I have to try your solution with "20:00" but change a little bit something like  LocalTime froms = LocalTime.parse("20:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH))  then use getMinute() . But It turns out of 0 minute instead of 1200 minutes. Why that does not 1200 ? Beacuse of What ?

Comment: Excuse me, sorry, I can say nothing about errors in your code when I cannot see your code.

Comment: `20:00` means that the hour of day is 20 and the minute of the hour is 0. So `froms.getHour()` gives you 20 and `froms.getMinute()` gives you 0. Your parsing is correct and you have got the expected `LocalTime` value.

Comment: How can I convert "20.30" to  "1230" minute ? Using Duration as your answer is possible ?

Comment: I think I got It !!  Using Duration.between("00:00" to "20:30")  ??

Comment: That should work, @Mr.Kim. Try it. "00:00" can be stated as `LocalTime.MIN` or `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` (whichever you prefer).